# why does a double form tag cause a linebreak in IE?

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer

I have this html script in a Web-Application.

I am aware, that this is **invalid HTML because I should not nest forms into each other**, but if "someone" did this nevertheless, how could I prevent that strange behaviour in IE? Is there a **workaround** with keeping that invalid forms inside?

```
<html><head>
    <style>
    form{
        display: inline;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table border="1">
                <tr>
                            <td>first</td>
                            <td><form>...</form></td>
                            <td>second</td>
                </tr>   
    </table>
</form>
```

which causes a linebreak between the "first" and "second" in Internet Explorer.

it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it is not possible to have a form nested into another one

Comment: A form nested inside a form is invalid HTML. You shouldn't do it, and if you do do it, then you should expect browsers to do unexpected things.

Answer (score 4):

It's invalid HTML, that's why. Internet Explorer interpretes the close tag of the second form as the close tag of the first form. It **DOESN'T*** create a second form.
However, due to this it's breaking the table and creating 2 table-structures in stead of 1. This is the root cause of why "second" is on a new line.

Please read [the W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) for more information. This part is very important:

> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

So it isn't a bug in Internet Explorer, it's a bug in your HTML markup. Internet Explorer just interpretes your buggy HTML code different than other browsers.

Comment: but it is still no solution. I need a workaround for that bad HTML

Comment: You asked why you had a linebreak, so my answer explains why you have it. But what you're asking is impossible. Your HTML code is just wrong, so fix it. This is the same as you would give me an equation "2 + 2 = 5". I can tell you what's wrong and give you the proper solution, but I cannot change mathematics so "2 + 2" would become 5.

Comment: Note this is fix-up behaviour is only IE versions < 10. IE10 does the same as other browsers. Good answer. +1

Comment: Yes, your answer is good, and my problem is evil. But It would be nice to have a workaround too ;)

Comment: Did you read my other comment? It's impossible. Is there a workaround for "2 + 2" so it would become 5? No there isn't. The only solution to the problem is to change the answer to 4, or in your case, by changing the HTML code. You can expect a workaround if there's some odd behavior. This isn't odd behavior, this is the best a browser can make of it.

Answer (score 1):

use `float: left;` for form- coz A `<form>` element is a block-level element,
and also you missed `}` in the style tag

Answer (score 0):

You could try and set some CSS styles to form, like padding:0px; and margin:0px;

You may need to create a class name and apply this to the class and not the 'form' in general or you may get undesired results.

By the way, some will rightly argue you should not have nested forms (forms within forms)